# T-SQL concatenation issue with NULLS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do a simple concatenation but failing somewhere! I want to display the Note in the email only if the other two variables are not empty. Even if one variable contains data it should display the Note. Below is my code.

```
SET @Note = CASE 
               WHEN @tableHTML_AssignedTo IS NOT NULL OR @tableHTML_SubmittedBy IS NOT NULL
                  THEN 'Note: The tickets with the following statuses are not listed in this alert: Closed,Rejected' 
                  ELSE NULL
            END

SET @ComposeBody = ISNULL(@tableHTML_AssignedTo, '') +
                   ISNULL(@tableHTML_SubmittedBy, '') +
                   ISNULL(@Note, '')
```

I know it's simple code but it's not obvious to my mind what I'm doing wrong. But with my code, an empty email is sent if both the tables are empty with Notes. If I remove Notes, no email is sent but I want to add the Notes in the email

Note: I'm executing this code inside cursor to send emails recursively

Comment: And would you mind explaining what's not working?

Comment: Instead of using ISNULL(x,'') over and over it's much simpler to use CONCAT(x,x,x)

Comment: @AnthonyHancock, That is if he using `SQL-Server 2012` or later.

Comment: Concat gives me the same Issue. The first two variables are HTML tables I contructed to send in an email. If I dont have any values in those two tables, I should not be sending emails to the folks in the loop. But with my code, an empty email is sent if both the tables are empty with Notes. If I remove Notes , no email is sent but I want to add the Notes in the email @Lamak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this -- seems simpler.

The trick here is to understand how null works with concat.  Anything concat with null is null.  So the first parameter to COALESCE will be null if Assigned or submitted is null.  Each next step checks the other two cases.

```
SET @Note = 'Note: The tickets with the following statuses are not listed in this alert: Closed,Rejected'; 

SET @ComposeBody = COALESCE(
     @tableHTML_AssignedTo+@tableHTML_SubmittedBy+@Note,  -- Selected if both non null
     @tableHTML_AssignedTo+@Note,                         -- Selected if SubmittedBy null
     @tableHTML_SubmittedBy+@Note)                        -- Selected if AssignedTo null
                       -- Both are null, set body to null.
```

Comment: @Matt -- I believe the OP does want that case to have the @note.  But if he doesn't he can modify the first parameter to coalesce to be `@tableHTML_AssignedTo+@tableHTML_SubmittedBy` ... Simple.  As you can see with this method you can change the note for each case.

Comment: Comment above was about how to not include the note if both are non-null.